# do we need to write seperate .js.erb files for each ajax request we do in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to ruby on rails and i want to learn to use ajax in it. I have gone through few tutorials.  My question is if we hav many forms, buttons that uses ajax requests should we write .js.erb files for each requests or can we have a single file which renders different responses for different requests? Can we have those responses from controller itself?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to provide a js.erb file, but if you want to do something dynamic to the page, you're going to have to have SOMETHING to render.

Obviously if all you're doing is putting something in the flash and returning it, a view isn't needed.

Comment: can i update view just from controller without writing js file?

Comment: no… look at the controller as a 'traffic cop', not something that really does anything. So, if you want to update the view, create the js.erb file and add the js response to the respond_to block.